# MySQL shell error while attempting to connect

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to configure a MySQL server for a wordpress.org project on Windows. However, I can't seem to connect to the MySQL server via MySQL shell.

when I inputted the command `\connect root@localhost`, and entered the password, I got an error:

`MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I assumed that I had forgot my password, and tried saving a txt file with the command
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Yet I got the same error message. I then reset the password with `mysqld --skip -grant`, and when I restarted MySQL and tried to use `\connect`, I got the error

`MySQL Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I also tried `mysql -u root -p`, but got the error

`ERROR: Not connected.`

Basically everything that didn't start with `\` generated a Not Connected error.

I tried using the Command Prompt instead of the MySQL shell, but got the exact same error.
How can I properly access MySQL?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux or Mac? Have you installed MySQL Server?

Comment: I am using Windows 11. Yes, I have MySQL Server installed.

Comment: Go to your services and see if MySQL service is running. If it is not running, you should start the service and ensure the service stays running (and doesn't stop automatically). If you need to change the root password, use this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/8.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html. Then, download and install MySQL Workbench, which gives you a GUI to connect. Ensure you can connect to your MySQL server using Workbench. Once that works well, you can choose to go to command line and try logging in.